# How to add up the total of 1 array + the total of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I am a rookie beginner with PHP, i was wondering how i could add up the total number from 1 array + the total number of another array together. I managed to make this code with help from stackoverflow answers on google. I don't know why but it's no where explained or i am looking over it. Been looking for almost an hour to make this work. Here is the code:

```
<?php 

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19);

$odds = array();
$even = array();

foreach($array as $val) {
    if($val % 2 == 0) {
        $even[] = $val;
    } else {
        $odds[] = $val;
    }
}



$array = array();
foreach($even as $key => $val) {
    $array[] = $val;
    if(isset($odds[$key])) {
        $array[] = $odds[$key];
    }
}

echo '<b>Oneven</b> ';
print_r($odds);

echo '<br><br><br>';

echo "Bovenstaande <b>oneven</b> getallen bijelkaar opgeteld = " . array_sum($odds) . "\n";
echo '<br><br><br><hr style="margin-top:2%;margin-bottom:4%;">';

/* Array nummer 2 */


$array = array(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40);

$odds = array();
$even = array();

foreach($array as $val) {
    if($val % 2 == 0) {
        $even[] = $val;
    } else {
        $odds[] = $val;
    }
}

$array = array();

foreach($even as $key => $val) {
    $array[] = $val;
    if(isset($odds[$key])) {
        $array[] = $odds[$key];
    }
}
echo '<b>Even</b> ';
print_r($even);
echo '<br><br><br>';

echo "Bovenstaande <b>even</b> getallen bijelkaar opgeteld = " . array_sum($even) . "\n";



?>
```

So i don't know how to do it in another way but i have array 1 code at first and then code 2 begins with another array.

The thing is that i want to make a program that includes the odd numbers from 1 to 19 and the even numbers from 20 to 40 and then count the total of those 2 array's. Is there a way to do this in 1 code and count up the total of those 2 array's together. I already have that part of code that it counts the array, in code 1 that is 100 and in code 2 it is 330.

330+100=430 that's the output that i want. Why is that so hard? haha...

I appreciate the help and time effort.

Comment: How about `array_merge()`ing , then `array_sum()`ing? Something like that?

Comment: Just add another condition where you check if the number is even or odd to also check if the number is `<` or `>=` 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there's a lot of complexity involved in creating the initial array and then extracting only the odd numbers. This complexity can be eliminating by using the `range` and `array_filter` functions like so:

```
$odds = array_filter(range(1, 19), function($elem) {
    return $elem & 1;
});

$even = array_filter(range(20, 40), function($elem) {
    return $elem % 2 == 0;
});
```

to calculate sum of the sum of `odds` plus the sum of `even`, you can simply merge them together and use `array_sum` in the same you are doing for the individual arrays

```
$totalSum = array_sum(array_merge($odds, $even))
```

---

As @Darragh pointed out in the comments, you can simplify the array creation by specifying a `step` parameter for the `range` function.

```
$odds = range(1, 19, 2) // start at 1, go up to 19, by increments of 2
```

Comment: `range()` accepts a third "step" argument, so you can alternatively create a sequence of odd numbers with `$odds = range(1, 19, 2);` and sequence of even numbers with `$evens = range(20, 40, 2);`

Comment: @DarraghEnright Did not know that, I'll include it in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guy's it is so fun to start this adventure on PHP. Thank's to the explanation from you guy's! In dutch we say 'TOP' that means 'perfect/great' haha